# How can i make an application invisible in recent apps?

Tags: android

I want to run an application in background, I already tried to change the manifest file by adding `android:noHistory="true"` and  `android:excludeFromRecents="true"`, but it is still visible.

I also tried to add flags to the Intent, but it's still not working.
Can anybody help me figure out what the problem is?

```
<activity android:name=".Seconde" 
android:noHistory="true"  
android:excludeFromRecents="true" 
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoDisplay" 
android:label="@string/title_activity_seconde" > 
</activity>
```

Comment: Where in your manifest file did you place those attributes?

Comment: <activity
            android:name=".Seconde"
            android:noHistory="true"
            android:excludeFromRecents="true"
             android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoDisplay"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_seconde" >
        </activity>

Comment: Is this the only activity you have? Did you try putting it on on activities ?

Comment: yes i  try  it on  other

Comment: Can you explain a bit more about exactly what you are trying to accomplish? What do you mean by run application in background?

Comment: great thanks to all for answering , i'm developping an android application in domain of security, i want to run an invisible application that the user can not see it running, i already succeed to make it invisible by using android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoDisplay" but the problem that the application still visible in the recent apps ,what i'm trying to accomplish is making the application not visible in the recent apps